# Capitalising Research & Development Expenses with a Pandas df

Tags: python, pandas

I am working on a project for my thesis, which has to do with the capitalization of Research & Development (R&D) expenses for a data set of companies that I have.

For those who are not familiar with financial terminology, I am trying to accumulate the values of each year's R&D expenses with the following ones by decaying its value (or "depreciating" it) every time period.

For example if we have Apple's R&D expenses for 5 years at a constant depreciation rate of 20%:

```
year  r&d_exp  dep_rate  r&d_capital

1999    10       0.2          10   
2000    8        0.2          16 
2001    12       0.2        24.4 
2002    7        0.2        25.4 
2003    15       0.2          33
```

If it was not clear, `r&d_capital` is retrieved the following way:

2000 = 10*(1-0.2) + 8

2001 = 10*(1-0.4) + 8*(1-0.2) + 12

2002 = 10*(1-0.6) + 8*(1-0.4) + 12*(1-0.2) + 7

2003 = 10*(1-0.8) + 8*(1-0.6) + 12*(1-0.4) + 7*(1-0.2) + 15

How can I automate this calculation in a pandas Dataframe? 
Also considering that I have more than 1 firm in my dataframe.

Thank you in advance for the help :)

Comment: what python version are you using 2.7 or 3? - also is the above example your expected output? if you have multiple firms can you add a column to illustrate that example?

Comment: Is it normal that discount factor is summing and not multiplying each year?

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? If you don't know how to use Pandas, you can find the documentation at https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/. Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure there's a better way to do it, but using a for loop and indexing you can add the `'r&d_exp'` and `'dep_rate'` appropriately:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(((1999, 10, 0.2, 10),
                   (2000, 8 , 0.2,   16),
                   (2001, 12, 0.2, 24.4),
                   (2002, 7 , 0.2, 25.4),
                   (2003, 15, 0.2,   33)),
                  columns=('year', 'r&d_exp', 'dep_rate', 'r&d_capital'))
```

we can use indexing and list comprehension to sum for each value up to each year:

```
# set to zero to show that correct values are recovered
df['r&d_capital'] = 0
print(df['r&d_capital'])
>>> np.array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0])

df['r&d_capital'] = [(df['r&d_exp'].iloc[:i] * (1 - df['dep_rate'].iloc[:i]*np.arange(i)[::-1])).sum()
                     for i in range(1, len(df)+1)]

df['r&d_capital'].values
>>> array([10. , 16. , 24.4, 25.4, 33. ])
```

We use `df['r&d_exp'].iloc[:i]` to extract the series up to index `i` and then use an array `np.arange(i)[::-1]` of indices to generate the total depreciation rate at the year in question. Importantly this array is reversed such that the earlier values have multiple integers of depreciation. This generates the value of what I assume is the initial investment after depreciation at the year in question. All of these contributions are then summed to get the total capital. This method will already handle different depreciation rates.

In principle this can be extended to other firms easily.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, that was super helpful :) Thank you Paddy!

Comment: Although I am having troubles implementing it in a panel data with many firms :P